# Why are question with bounty not closable?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

A question ([Is post-COVID flying more dangerous?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/80081/3394)) that seems to be answerable only with subjective answer has an open bounty (on friday the 7th of august 2020). I would like to add it to the "close vote" review queue as "opinion-based", but I get the error message "open bounty & cannot be closed". Reading the comment, it seems I'm not the only one affected by that feature.

There could be other older questions that did not received attention at all, with no answer, and that should have been closed or deleted long ago. But as they never get activity, nobody see them anymore. Such a question can suddenly have an open bounty while it still should be closed.

Why does this feature (unable to close a question with an open bounty) exists? In which cases is it useful? Do we need to propose a modification on this feature to be able to close question while a bounty is open?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Questions can only receive a bounty 48 hours or later after they're posted. Most off-topic questions are closed before somebody gets a chance to put a bounty on them.

In (relatively rare) cases like this, you can just flag the question for ♦ moderator attention (indicate that you use a custom flag instead of a regular close vote because of the bounty). They will be able to cancel the bounty and close the question.

A feature request to allow voting to close a bountied post has been proposed a long time ago on Meta Stack Exchange: [Allow users to vote to close bountied questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121448/295232) but a former employee stated that [such a function isn't necessary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137432/295232).

Comment: Ho!? nice suggestion (I didn't know moderators were powerful enough).

Answer (score 0):

Well, we've got another bountied question, and it's, um, interesting:

[Who must approve a globally distributed satellite to ground laser communication system?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/32332/who-must-approve-a-globally-distributed-satellite-to-ground-laser-communication)

How on earth (or, in orbit) this question didn't get closed before as (wildly) off-topic is beyond me, but there it is, with a bounty to keep it present for the next 6 days.

I've flagged it for the Mods; hopefully that gets it into the review queue quickly.

I'm not agreeing with the "ah, that happens almost never, we don't need to change the rules" line of reasoning right now!